# "registration_ids" field cannot be empty (laravel and Firebase)

Tags: laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing problem with Firebase "registration_ids". I want to send push notifications from my laravel website to mobile devices and When I send notification in view i get error:

"registration_ids" field cannot be empty

here is my blade script:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();  

function initFirebaseMessagingRegistration() {

        messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then(function () {
            return messaging.getToken()
        })
        .then(function(token) {
            console.log(token);

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });  

            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route("save-token") }}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    token: token
                },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Token saved successfully.');
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log('User Chat Token Error'+ err);
                },
            });
  
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('User Chat Token Error'+ err);
        });
 }        

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    const noteTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const noteOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: payload.notification.icon,
    };

    new Notification(noteTitle, noteOptions);
});
```

and here is my controller:

```
public function saveToken(Request $request)
{
    auth()->user()->update(['device_token'=>$request->token]);
    return response()->json(['token saved successfully.']);
}  

/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */

public function sendNotification(Request $request)
{
    $firebaseToken = User::whereNotNull('device_token')->pluck('device_token')->all();

    $SERVER_API_KEY = 'mine';

    $data = [
        "registration_ids" => $firebaseToken,
        "notification" => [
            "title" => $request->title,
            "body" => $request->body,  
        ]
    ];

    $dataString = json_encode($data);

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: key=' . $SERVER_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    dd($response);
}
```

I can not fix the problem.
Can anybody help me plz?

Comment: It looks like `User::whereNotNull('device_token')->pluck('device_token')->all();` returns no results. We have no way to say why that is based on the code shared.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please Update your Device Token in user table

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `device_token` column is empty.

```
User::whereNotNull('device_token')->pluck('device_token')->all()
```

It returns `0` so that `registration_ids` field cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add these two lines to `routes/web.php`:

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

2. In firebase, go to Project Settings->General->Your apps, and add WEB (SDK). Among other things, a code sample will be generated. From there copy the section that starts: "apiKey: ..." and ends in "measurementId:..."
3. Paste the values from step 2, into `resources/views/home.blade.php`, at line 44
4. Paste the values from step 2, into `public/firebase-messaging-sw.js`, at line 11

   Try again the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login`

[source](https://github.com/SinghDigamber/laravel_web_push_notification/issues/1)

Comment: Thanks @Abilogos